# Using NaN in if and interp1 commands

Tags: matlab, if-statement, interpolation

I have a problem when I use the 'isnan' command in the code below.

I have 6 values, some of which are NaNs. If 'interp1' command finds the final value as NaN for giving 'c', MATLAB must give me error message.

```
a=[1 2 3 4 5 6];
b=[10 15 20 NaN NaN NaN];
c=[1.5 4 3.5 4.5 5.1 5.9];
for g=1:1:numel(a)
if interp1(a,b,c(g))==NaN;
        disp('There is a mistake here')
   end
end
```

MATLAB, however, does't run this command with NaNs.

```
*In interp1 at 178
Warning: NaN found in Y, interpolation at undefined values
     will result in undefined values.*
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is your matlab version?

this code work for me (matlab R2013b):

```
a=[1 2 3 4 5 6];
b=[10 15 20 NaN NaN NaN];
c=[1.5 4 3.5 4.5 5.1 5.9];
for g=1:1:numel(a)
if isnan(interp1(a,b,c(g)))
        disp('There is a mistake here')
   end
end
```

Comment: R2008b. This code works on my software, too but gives me warning error: Warning: NaN found in Y, interpolation at undefined values
  will result in undefined values. 
> In interp1 at 178

Comment: ok , so it is working, it just says that when you have undefined value the output of interpolation is undefined , if it is ok with you just ignore it

Comment: Thank you daren shan. Now i am using the code and it works wonderful.